# Performance of LINQ Any vs FirstOrDefault != null

Tags: c#, linq

There are multiple places in an Open Source Project (OSP) code I contribute, where it has to be determined if an element in a collection satisfies a certain condition.

I've seen the use of LINQ expression `Any(lambda expression)` in some cases and `FirstOrDefault(lambda expression) != null` in others but never given a thought about it.

I have reached now a point where I have to do some iterations to collections made from  queries to a DB and want to optimize the runtime.

So I figured that `FirstOrDefault(lambda expression) != null` should be faster than `Any(lambda expression)`,right?

In the case of `FirstOrDefault(lambda expression) != null`, the iteration (probably) stops when it finds an element that satisfies the condition (worse case scenario it iterates through the entire collection and returns `null`).

In the case of `Any(lambda expression)` I imagine that the iteration continues to the end of the collection even if an element that satisfies the condition is found.

Edit: The above is not true as Jackson Pope mentioned and linked the related MSDN article.

Are my thoughts correct or am I missing something?

Comment: "in the case of `Any(lambda expression)` I imagine that the iteration continues to the end of the collection even if an element that satisfies the condition is found". Why?

Comment: Because I didn't read the MSDN article as Jackson Pope mentioned. lol

Comment: nor did I - I just had no reason to assume that LINQ implementation is nonsensical

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The enumeration in `Any()` stops as soon as it finds a matching item as well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any

I would expect the performance to be very similar. Note that the `FirstOrDefault` version won't work with a collection of value types (since the default isn't null) but the `Any` version would.

Comment: So is it a case of use `Any()` when you want to know if something exists that meets a specified criteria, but `FirstorDefault()` if you actually want that object back?

Comment: @Chris: Yeah, that's what I use.

Comment: Then why is `FirstOrDefault(lambda expression) != null` faster?
Done some `Ticks` testing and `FirstOrDefault(lambda expression) != null` always ends faster.

Comment: @Jimi you'll have to show us your testing code. It's hard to get right.

Comment: @AakashM It involves a query to a DB so even posting the code, you won't be able to test it.

Comment: @Jackson Pope It's always of reference types.

Comment: @Jackson Pope Runtime performance is my goal. Surely we are talking about trivial ms (milliseconds) difference in performance but still that `FirstOrDefault(lambda expression) != null` always ends first.

Comment: Please show some numbers. As I said in my other comment, the difference has nothing to do with the implementation of those two methods. See my answer for their code...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth They are not always the same and as I comment above, it ends up being of trivial importance. It's merely my curiosity rather than getting a scientific explanation.

Comment: @Jimi: There is no explanation to be found in the code of these methods. The reason for your results is something else - what? I don't know, because I don't know your test code.

Comment: My thanks to all of you guys for clearing this up for me. Respect.

Comment: in Oracle `Any()` causes full table scan, that's really a disaster

Comment: What about the fact that a default value of an integer is 0? I mean value types also have their 'default' values.

Answer (score 58):

You are mixing things here. You are talking about collections, but you don't seem to use LINQ to objects but you are querying a database.

**LINQ to objects:**
[`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) and [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault) should perform the same, because their code is near identical:

`FirstOrDefault`:

```
foreach (TSource source1 in source)
{
    if (predicate(source1))
        return source1;
}
return default (TSource);
```

`Any`:

```
foreach (TSource source1 in source)
{
    if (predicate(source1))
        return true
}
return false;
```

**LINQ to some database:**
You are using Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL or NHibernate and use [`Queryable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.any) and [`Queryable.FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault) on the corresponding data context.
In this case, there are really no collections, because these calls are not executed on in memory objects but translated to SQL.

This means, the performance difference stems from how the LINQ provider translates the code to SQL, so the best would be to first check the statements created. Are they equivalent? Or are they very different (`select count(0) from X` vs. `select top 1 from X`)? Then the difference might lie in the query optimizer of the DB, indexes and what not...

Comment: You have a point here. We do DB queries by use of Entity and store the tables in collections. Then we iterate through those collections to extracting the data we want using LINQ.

Comment: @Jimi: I don't understand your comment, sorry. Maybe you want to rephrase or expand it.

Comment: So in that case you are using LINQ to objects. The difference you are measuring in your tests is not coming from the implementation of the two methods, but from your test setup or something else. See update answer for the implementations of the two methods.

Comment: The 'FirstOrDefault' will have to return the actual data from the object, so if there is a smaller index, the 'Any' call _should_ have potential to be much faster. Especially in a wide table with many columns.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with this question is that it is not asked within context.
I am providing an answer because I see this a lot in code reviews and it bothers me.
LINQ should not be an excuse to stop thinking.

```
var people = new [] { "Steve", "Joe" };

if (people.Any(s => s == "Joe"))
{
    var joe = people.First(s => s == "Joe");
    // do something with joe
}

// if people is 1,000,000 people and joe is near the end do we want BigO to approach 2N here at worst case ?

var joe1N = people.FirstOrDefault(s => s == "Joe");
if (joe1N != null)
{
    // do something with joe
}

// or do we want to ensure worst case is N by simply using a variable ?
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question... Since I'm late to the party: I really don't know what you want to tell us. That we, in this case, should use `FirstOrDefault` or that we should use `Any` + `First`? I don't get the point. Can you (or someone else) explain?

Comment: I see your point that first approach is twice slower, but BigO 2N is still N

Answer (score 3):

Why should any continue after it has found an element satisfying the condition? If the condition applies to 1 element, that qualifies as "any".

I think they should both perform about the same, but Any() does express your intention more clearly.

Comment: True. My question is not about expressing intention and code readability but rather runtime performance.

Comment: Any() is cleaner - but also FirstOrDefault() would normally try to return the first item found, so technically it would hog bandwidth with unneeded return data. Practically, optimization within LINQ probably keeps that from happening, but do you want to depend on that?

Answer (score 1):

My two cents...

I had a huge performance issue with Any(). I am using Telerik grid to display a list of related data, ie,

-I have a "PEOPLE" table

-A "COMPANY" table

-A "PEOPLE_COMPANY" link table

-A "PEOPLE_ROL" link table

-And a "ROL" table with main category, subcategory and description.

The view mixes data and has a few properties which loads data on demand about specific roles (admin, reporter, manager).

```
var x = GetPeople().Where(p => p.ROLs.Any(i => i.USO_Id == MainCatId && i.TUP_Id == (int)RolType) && p.PER_Id != per_id);

var x = GetPersonas().Where(p => p.ROLs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.USO_Id == MainCatId && i.TUP_Id == (int)RolType) != null && p.PER_Id != per_id);
```

My grid uses AJAX, and takes over 10 seconds to load using "Any", and 3 or less using "FirstOrDefault". Had not taken the time to debug it as requieres to intercept calls from telerik components and my model.

Hope this helps... so test it well :)

Comment: I prefer to not use a condition on First or Any. Instead, I use a Where (e.g. `Where(i => i.USO_Id == MainCatId && i.TUP_Id == (int)RolType) && p.PER_Id != per_id).Any()`)

Comment: @Jorge - thanks, great example. In my case (NH 3.3.1 on SQL Server 2005), my `.Any()` takes 15 seconds, and the equivalent `.FirstOrDefault() != null` is consistently sub-second.

Answer (score 1):

We can use **.Count(x => x....)** != 0 instead of using **.Any(x => x....) or .FirstOrDefault(x => x....) != null**

Because query generation of Linq is below,

(In Any(), the 2nd(Not Exists) condition is not need i think.)

**.Any(x => x.Col_1 == 'xxx')**

```
    (@p__linq__0 varchar(8000))SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Table_X] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Col_1] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Table_X] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent2].[Col_1] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

**.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Col_1 == 'xxx') != null**

```
 (@p__linq__0 varchar(8000))SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[Col_1] AS [Col_1], 
[Extent1].[Col_2] AS [Col_2], 
...
[Extent1].[Col_n] AS [Col_n]
FROM [dbo].[Table_X] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Col_1] = @p__linq__0
```

**.Count(x => x.Col_1 == 'xxx') != 0**

```
  (@p__linq__0 varchar(8000))SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[Table_X] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[Col_1] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Comment: Yes, both the .Any and the .Count methods could hit the same index (less data, faster than the table), but it would depend on how the index is organized and how many rows the table has. The .Any implementation should be the fastest one.

Comment: But my thought is, For ".Any" implementation, if the 1st when condition fails, then it will execute the 2nd when condition. So the ".Any" executing the two statements to return false result.

Answer (score 1):

Although it has similar implementation, I believe Any is a bit faster because it doesn't have to return an object, which in some cases may be rich, with state and behavior, depends on how well the query is thought out.