# Best way to determined null or count 0

Tags: c#, linq

I have a iQueryable and I need to know if it's null or has no values.

```
IQueryable<people> L = (from p in people 
                        where p.lastname.Contains("y") 
                        select p);
if (L != null && L.Count() > 0) {
   return "Something";
} else {
   return "NOTHING";
}
```

Well if you use the `L.Count()` it will use more resources.  Is there a better way?  Something that does not use `L.Count()`

Comment: If you call `SingleOrDefault`, how can `L`  be an `IQueryable<people>`?

Comment: You are correct, I did not have `.SingleOrDefault` in my code. Please edit that out in your mind.

Comment: You can edit your question by clicking the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9414805/edit) link below your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's recommended that you use `.Any()`.

```
IQueryable<people> L = (from p in people 
                        where p.lastname.Contains("y") 
                        select p);
if (L.Any()) {
   return "Something";
} else {
   return "NOTHING";
}
```

Comment: We did code comparison and `.Count` vs `.Any` were almost the same.  But I like the `.Any` better.  I have not checked how SQL deals with it but I can do that later.  Thanks!

Comment: In the case where the enumerable is empty or has only one or two values, OR where the method is applied directly to a source IEnumerable that is also identifiable as an ICollection or an Array (and thus having a Count or Length property), Count() will perform roughly the same as Any(). Where Any() really shines is in long collections; Any() performs constantly (O(1)), while Count() performs linearly (O(N)). Both are "fast" by most algorithmic measures, but Any()'s faster.

Comment: Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, and recent NHibernate providers all handle `Any` in a special, performant manner. You can see an example  of what it generates by using LINQPad. Pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

Does L need to be IQueryable<> ? 
By using SingleOrDefault() it will be a single people (Person?) or null (presuming people is a class)

```
var result = (from p in people  
              where p.lastname.Contains("y")  
              select p).SingleOrDefault(); 

return result == null
        ? "NOTHING"
        : "Something";
```

*Other:* Is SingleOrDefault() what you want to use or do you mean FirstOrDefault() or do you mean Any()?

Maybe [LINQ: When to use SingleOrDefault vs. FirstOrDefault() with filtering criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria) can help.

hth, 
Alan.

Answer (score 1):

`L.Any()`, `L.FirstOrDefault()` will pretty much both have the same performance as they have almost identical implementation and are probably what you are looking for. Your SingleOrDefault is probably unintentional as it will throw an exception if there is more than one result.

[Performance of LINQ Any vs FirstOrDefault != null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339988/performance-of-linq-any-vs-firstordefault-null)

It's worth saying some of this depends on your provider. IQueryable just implies an intention. If It's Linq2Sql or something then yes L.Count() will request more resources - except that your also calling SingleOrDefault in the above line which means your null check is all you need, but your types don't match...

If I am running this statement against a Linq provider I write myself (or Amazons, or any other given LINQ provider) *.Count() might be faster* depending on what the provider is doing, but your assumptions hold if you're using the usual Microsoft Linq to SQL implementations.

Answer (score 1):

An example of using the .Any method

```
return people.Any(p => p.lastname.Contains("y")) ? "something" : "nothing";
```

This is an example that would return an IQueryable if the .Any returns true, however it might be too ineffecient since it requires two round trips to the database. I'm sure a better method could be written, given enough time and thought.

```
      return sis.Students.Any(p => p.LastName.Contains("y")) ? 
        people.Where(p => p.lastname.Contains("y")) : "nothing";
```