# Performance of Any vs FirstOrDefault

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

So I've been digging in queries EF produces for our app and I noticed some strange sql generation of `Any` calls - they seem to be overly complicated. `Any` seem to generate `case when (x) then 1 when (not x) then 0 end` - why not just use else? This way SQL server has to execute the same query twice in cases where `Any` should return `false`. I came up with workaround that seem to be faster in those cases using `Where(cond).Select(q => true).FirstOrDefault()`, but I'm still interested in whether this is just oversight or it has some meaning I'm missing.

`context.Books.Any(b => b.Id == bookId);`

```
declare @p__linq__0 Int = 1;

SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [Books] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [Books] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent2].[ID] = @p__linq__0
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

`context.Books.Where(b => b.ID == bookId).Select(b => true).FirstOrDefault();`

```
declare @p__linq__0 Int = 1;

SELECT TOP (1) 
cast(1 as bit) AS [C1]
FROM [Books] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = @p__linq__0
```

Comment: "This way SQL server has to execute the same query twice" - that's an assumption. The optimizer may be able to spot that the same subquery is being executed - it's not a correlated subquery, so it may actually only execute it once. You'd need to use a profiler or obtain execution plans to know for sure (so, as always, don't *assume* you know where any performance issues will arise - measure first).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm sorry, I didn't mention it, but I did check the execution plan and it indeed executes given step again when first condition is not met.

Comment: Same QA available here [StackOverFlow: Performance of LINQ Any vs FirstOrDefault != null][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339988/performance-of-linq-any-vs-firstordefault-null/25930973#25930973

Answer (score 1):

After you have seen that something does not exists it is pretty clear that it does indeed not exists, so checking agin if is really does not exist is not necessary. This is just one of those cases where linq is producing overly complicated queries. Your workaround works, but it is not necessarily as easy to understand as one would like, so I suggest to take the performance hit of the original linq until it really becomes a performance problem. Just make sure there is an index on the Id column.

Comment: I understand, that in case of simple query over an index the performance loss is neglible, but relatively we are speaking of ±24% longer execution time (tested on simple query over 5000000 iterations) and that's a lot when you find yourself executing `Any` on more complex query that can take tens milliseconds or even hundreds milliseconds.

Comment: If it is a performance problem by all means use your workaround. Just make sure you comment the code as to why it is written as it is, so that the next person does not "clean" it up again.