# In Entity Framework, which is faster Any() or FirstOrDefault()?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5

I'm a newbie in Entity Framework and SQL. I would like to know which one is (a little) faster: `Any()` or `FirstOrDefault()`. See below of how I want to use them.

**Option 1**

```
if(Comments.Select(c=>c.ObjectId).FirstOrDefault()>0) {...}
```

*Generated SQL*

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[c].[ObjectId] AS [ObjectId]
FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [c]
```

**Option 2**

```
if(Comments.Select(c=>c.ObjectId).Any()) {...}
```

*Generated SQL*

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent1]
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Comments] AS [Extent2]
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

Comment: Well did you forget to post the benchmarks for each ?

Comment: From http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ _If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses**._

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339988/performance-of-linq-any-vs-firstordefault-null

Comment: Guess what i was just about to read this [performance benchmark mistakes -Eric Lippert](https://tech.pro/tutorial/1295/c-performance-benchmark-mistakes-part-two)