# Which is fast between WHERE and ANY in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have two linq expression giving the same result. Can anyone explains which is fast between them and why?

```
if (lstEmployees.Where(cond => cond.EmployeeID == empID).Select(col => col.IsManager).FirstOrDefault())
{
...
}
```

or

```
if (lstEmployees.Any(cond => cond.EmployeeID == empID && cond.IsManager))
{
...
}
```

Comment: `Any` will always be just as fast or faster.

Comment: This expressions can't give you the same result. .FirstOrDefault is returning a TSource, where `Any` is returning a boolean

Comment: possible duplicate of [Performance of LINQ Any vs FirstOrDefault != null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339988/performance-of-linq-any-vs-firstordefault-null)

Comment: @rdoubleui damnit. You are right.

Comment: @Serv - "IsManager" is bolean column in my query so ultimately we will get the same result.

Comment: Is this actually causing and issue? Did you test this? The difference in execution speed is likely to be so small that you won't ever notice.

Comment: @Serv - The code in first example is working fine at my end.

Comment: @DevD Haven't claimed otherwise.

Comment: Do you care how fast it is? Do you have any evidence that your code is running slow because of this?

Comment: Your first query checks whether the *first* employee record is a manager record and then quits. Your second query will also check further records (if available)

Comment: The difference is futile. It's impossible to tell anything sensible about it. Both queries stop at the first match (If the SQL translations do any justice to the query semantics). The defining factor here is the RDBMS implementation and their specific differences between `EXISTS` and `TOP` concepts.

Answer (score 0):

```
lstEmployees.Any(cond => cond.EmployeeID == empID && cond.IsManager)
```

It should be fast. It is only check to data available or not and return true or false. 
second method should return object.

Comment: Returning a reference to a pre-existing object is not a slow operation.

Comment: Totally agree with Gusdor!

Answer (score 0):

Any() will stop iterating at the first item that meets your condition and simply return a bool (true = found or false not found). Where() will continue through the whole sequence so that it can return a complete result of items where your condition matches. In Summary - Any() is your faster solution if you just need to know if a condition is true at least once and don't care about the actual items that meet your condition.

Here is the implementation of Any(). See how it exits out of the foreach loop as soon as the predicate returns true.

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (predicate(element)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT: As per the comment - for the Where() expression to filter the sequence it actually needs to be evaluated. The chosen evaluation will determine if you actually go through the whole sequence or not. So if for example you do a foreach printing out all the results you will go through the whole sequence. Using FirstOrDefault() on the Where() you may also get the benefit of early termination. Any() is evaluated immediately.

Comment: While you're correct that `Where` will iterate over the whole sequence, it won't do so until the sequence is enumerated, and the subsequent `FirstOrDefault` call will similarly terminate the enumeration when the first element is found.

Comment: Thanks @IainGalloway I added a comment which hopefully makes that point.

Answer (score 0):

In theory

```
lstEmployees.Any(cond => cond.EmployeeID == empID && cond.IsManager)
```

should be faster or equal. Because it will do all necessary with one iteration loop.
BUT in reality it much depends on LINQ provider. There is a chance that provider will optimize

```
lstEmployees.Where(cond => cond.EmployeeID == empID).Select(col => col.IsManager).FirstOrDefault()
```

to more simple query and you will not feel any difference at all.

But I think that it's better to use .Any here, just because it's shorter and business logic is more clear and understandable.

Answer (score 0):

`Any` will be more correct in your case. Because Any will return true on first entity in collection which meets your condition, however  `FirstOrDefault` will do the same in your case(from the performance point of view). The only case when `FirstOrDefault` can be more slow is when you use third party data connectors with `bad` implementation of translation linq expressions to SQL query.

So generally just use `Any` to be sure that you use the fastest solution.