# Is there any difference in performance between these two LINQ to SQL queries?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I've been recently looking into my web app performance and found some LINQ queries that I'm not sure if changing them would improve performance.

Basically the current code looks like:

```
var result = _carsRepository.GetAll()
                 .Where(x => x.Name == input.Name)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null)
{
    throw new Exception("test");
}
```

I'm thinking of changing it to:

```
    var result = _carsRepository.GetAll()
                     .Where(x => x.Name == input.Name)
                     .Any();
if (result)
{
    throw new Exception("test");
}
```

In my understanding the first query would return an actual entity, which I don't need because I only want to know whether the record with the same name already exists in the database. The second query returns just a bool.

I'd be thankful for any comments.

EDIT: I could be running the query on EF db context, so please ignore that. 
The current repository is a generic Abp.Domian.Repository.
GetAll() returns IQueryable

Comment: general rule of thumb: test both, get a benchmark. avoid premature optimization, care only if this has been identified as a performance bottleneck in the application.

Comment: You could be pulling 100000000 records back from the database, before you do a `where`, if not, you probably need to index `Name`

Comment: @Saruman: index or not on Name is not relevant for this question because the `Where` is exactly the same in both queuries.

Comment: @TimSchmelter you are correct, however im just guessing ahead, before i wander off on to the next question

Comment: Unless explicitly identified as a bottleneck (through measurement), performance is seldom a good reason to change code. The better reason to change the code in this case is that the version using `.Any()` expresses the intent of what you're doing more clearly.

Comment: General rule, if you only need a Boolean back use the Linq function that does just that. Maybe it does not make much difference in performance, but it more clearly shows your intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. They are very helpful. I'm just wondering why somebody has downvoted my question? What have I done wrong? I'm just trying to learn from more experienced developers.

Comment: There´s nothing really *whring*. However you could have easily tried it out yourself.

Comment: Yes, I could have tried it myself, but I asked this question, because I knew I would get more than a simple answer. @jeroenh highlighted that using Any() makes more sense in terms of what I want to achieve.

Comment: What does `GetAll()` return?  And don't say 'all records', specify the Type.

Comment: I edited the question just now. It returns IQueryable<TEntity>

Comment: @Grentley is this code in a loop? it can be faster if it is.

Comment: You don't want all the cars, you wan't the list of car's name to see if one match. You don't have to get the whole object if you wan't only one field. So I will go for the most readable one `_carsRepository.GetAll().Any(x => x.Name == input.Name)` This way no object return from db only a bool.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8340268/6527049

Comment: And Exception should be exceptional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `GetAll()` does. If it moves all items from your database to your local memory, then I wouldn't bother: try to improve that statement. Why fetch all items if you only need the first one.

If `GetAll()` returns an `IQueryable<...>`, then there is a slight difference:

`FirstOrDefault()` will change the Expression in the query, such that the SQL statement will be `Select top 1 ... from`.

After changing the expression it will ask the `Provider` of the `IQqueryable` to execute the `Expression`, the complete result of the SQL statement will b transferred to local memory, which in this case will be one item.

`Any()` will almost do the same, except that the SQL will be: `Select top 1 1 from ...`

It is easy to see that a `Select top 1 1` will at utmost transfer one integer, while `Select top 1` will transfer all selected columns.

Hence, if you only want to check if there are any elements, `Any()` is more efficient then `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 3):

We cannot tell you, because neither do we know what your repository class does, nor do we know how your database driver handles transformation to SQL.

Test both, benchmark them, look at the SQL and check with your database analysis tools if you are maybe missing an index or other optimization opportunity.

From just the Linq it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Is this really an **answer**? Sounds like a comment to me. The question is - as you correctly pointed out - un-answerable.

Comment: @HimBromBeere In my view, telling somebody *why* it cannot be done *can* be an answer, especially if it contains alternative steps forward. But feel free to let reviewers decide.

Comment: I should have put some more details in my question. My question is very generic, I could be doing a LINQ on a stand EF db context. I just wanted to know  how significant the difference is.

Answer (score 3):

There could be a slight difference because of

`.FirstOrDefault()` - Reads all the columns

`.Any()` - Just check if there are entries

Difference will be mostly based on data size and SQL structure, indexes and all. Recommend to benchmark them by testing

Comment: So you're saying if the table contained hundreds of columns, the difference would be quite significant?

Comment: That depends on the table columns and data. e.g. VARCHAR(MAX) column takes significant time compared to VARCHAR(20). There are many other factors. I am just answering the difference because of First() and Any()

Answer (score 2):

No. You may not get any performance difference. because

1) **Any()** will return as soon as it finds a match.

2) **FirstOrDefault()** iteration (probably) stops when it finds an element that satisfies the condition.

**LINQ to objects:**
**Enumerable.Any** and **Enumerable.FirstOrDefault** should perform the same, because their code is near identical:

**FirstOrDefault:**

```
foreach (TSource source1 in source)
{
    if (predicate(source1))
        return source1;
}
return default (TSource);
```

**Any:**

```
foreach (TSource source1 in source)
{
    if (predicate(source1))
        return true
}
return false;
```

Now. its looks like you are getting all the records from database in  memory and then applying the where clause.

try to avoid in memory loading data at a time.then it will be give you the performance difference

Comment: What if one of the columns is a 10mb byte array

Comment: it could be same in this case also

Comment: The question is not about linq2objects. So in case of FirstOrDefault a `select top 1 *` will be generated, and in case of a 10mb byte array as one of the columns that will be fetched. For `Any()` it would not.

Answer (score 1):

As stated before, it is unclear what your Repository does. However if you are following the RepositoryPattern, you should consider adding Any as a method in your repository.

```
public virtual bool Any(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return _context.Set<T>().Any(predicate);
}
```

This will ensure that your Any is executed on the database, as this method executes Any on/ as an IQueryable.

If you do not user Generics in your repository, then replace T with your target class.