# Best approach to determine if record exists in database using Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want to determine if a record exists in the database using Linq

I ran performace tests to determine which approach is faster, and they seem equivalent.

Option 1:

```cs
MyClass my_instance = (from q in data_context.MyClass where q.id == "my_id" select q).FirstOrDefault();
bool is_exists = (my_instance != null);
```

Option 2:

```cs
bool is_exists = data_context.MyClass.Any(q => q.id == "my_id");
```

Is there one way better than the other? Is there a different faster approach?

Comment: First approach will materialize an instance of your entity. So if you will do this often you will create a memory traffic

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339988/performance-of-linq-any-vs-firstordefault-null

Comment: Don't have access to dev env. at the moment, but if you run a trace on the SQL being generated by both statement you will see that they are both very fast. The main difference is probably (can't prove at the moment hence this is only a comment) that the Any version will probably just do a "Select 1" from your MyClass table to check the existence of a row, whereas the "select q" version will select a bunch of columns from that row (i.e. to map the object). So the Any() version will likely be more performant in general

Comment: @Rav This is `IQueryable<T>` and is translated to SQL, there is no enumeration at all.